# Django: the current state of the database isn't present in the clean method

Tags: django

I want to test validation during creation of new Name.

I have following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="names")

    def clean(self):
        """ Ensure that self.name is unique for a given project.

            If not, raise ValidationError.
        """
        names = [name.name for name in self.project.names.all()]
        if self.name in names:
            raise ValidationError(
                {"name": _("Such name already exists in this project")})
```

In my test I do the following:

1. Create testing project like this:

   proj = Project.objects.create(name="test_proj")
2. Create pre-existing name like this:

   Name.objects.create(name="pre_name", project= proj)
3. Send request to view, which create new Name and call validation.

My test debug print output shows the following:

```
Project id in test: 1
Project name set in test: <QuerySet [<Name: pre_name>]>
Project id in clean method: 1
Project name set in clean: <QuerySet []>
```

I dont really understand why names set of test_proj is empty in Name clean method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really need to show both your view and your actual test code. But note there's a much better way of achieving this, which is to set `unique_together = ('name', 'project')` in the Name model's Meta class, which will cause Django to check for uniqueness automatically.

Comment: Ok, I found bug introduced by my self. But thank you for a hint, I will use unique_together instead clean method :-)